# How to show boundaries of boxes in ipywidgets?

Tags: ipywidgets

I am writing GUI consisting of several ipywidgets - something like:

```
import ipywidgets as wi

grid = wi.GridBox([
    wi.HBox([wi.Label("some_text"), wi.Dropdown()]),
    wi.HBox([wi.Dropdown(), wi.Output()])
])

display(grid)
```

Is there a way to add visible frames around each widget area so that I can see their layout so that making adjustments is easier?